# Tabular Data With Paging and Sorting

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, wcf

My project details are as follows,

Project Type : WCF client project
Technology   : ASP.NET MVC

I am getting data from WCF service in the form of List<SomeInterface>, and the method for example "GetAllMessages(int ServiceChannel)" or the Interface "SomeInterface", doesn't expose PageSize,PageNumber.

I am not using Model,as the data is coming from WCF service.

How can i display the tabular data as well as add paging & sorting feature to it?

I have tried with MVCContrib,jqGrid. But i was not able to make them work.

So wanted to know, how to proceed on this one. Any ideas,insights will be helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

On the server side:

```
YourListObject.OrderBy(x => x.Field).Skip(5).Take(5);
```

Use the OrderBy, Skip and Take methods to return a subset of data from the List.